# kotlin sharedPreferences getBoolean Question

Tags: kotlin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxFNN.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyKJA.png)

In the lecture, 'key' appears in gray letters. But it's not like that when I write it.
Do you happen to know a solution?

I hope the key appears in gray letters.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the picture, on the second picture it possibly did not appear because of the space before "CHECKBOX"

but you can find the setting for that in:

`Preferences -> Editor -> General -> Code Completion.`

There you will see a "Parameter Info" section, which contains all of the options that you need